# How to create a partitioned Trino table on S3 (with sub-folders)

Tags: presto, trino

My s3 location has the below structure

```
s3://bucketname/snapshot/db_collection/snapshot1/*.parquet
s3://bucketname/snapshot/db_collection/snapshot2/*.parquet
s3://bucketname/snapshot/db_collection/snapshot3/*.parquet
```

What I want is

1. to be able to define the `trino` table at the level `s3://bucketname/snapshot/db_collection/`; so that if I query for a row and it exists in 2 snapshots then I get 2 rows as output. I was not able to find how to write a `create table query` for this use-case (which essentially is a partition use-case). Also note that the partition folder `snapshotX` is not of format `<abc>=<efg>` format.
2. is there any tool/ way which can generate the `table` automatically out of the `parquet` file or the `schema` -json file. Why I ask is because -- my parquet file has 150 columns and each column is again nested etc. Writing a table by hand is not easy
3. I tried to run `aws glue crawler` --to generate the table and use `athena` for querying, but when I run select query i get into weird errors which scares me out. So I don't want to use this path.

My existing table definition is as follows

```
create table trino.db_collection (
        col1 varchar,
        col2 varchar,
        col3 varchar
)with (
    external_location = 's3a://bucket/trino/db_collection/*',
    format = 'PARQUET'
)
```

My setup is `AWS EMR 6.8.0` with  `trino-v388`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding partitions:

1. As you mentioned, automatic partition discovery won't work because Trino looks for the hive format `col_name=value`. As a best practice I would recommend to run a one-time procedure to rename the keys, however, if this is not possible, you can still manually register partitions using the register_partition system procedure. It's just tedius to maintain.

`system.register_partition(schema_name, table_name, partition_columns, partition_values, location)`

Please note you'll also need to edit your installation config and enable this on the catalog properties file.

From the docs (https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#procedures.):

```
Due to security reasons, the procedure is enabled only when hive.allow-register-partition-procedure is set to true.
```

2. The partition column has to be in the last in your table schema, and the parittioned_by property defined in the table properties.

So in your example:

```
create table trino.db_collection (
        col1 varchar,
        col2 varchar,
        col3 varchar,
        snapshot varchar
)with (
    external_location = 's3a://bucket/trino/db_collection/*',
    format = 'PARQUET',
    partitioned_by = ['snapshot']
)
```

Regarding inferring the table schema:

1. This is not supported in Trino but can be done in Spark/Glue Crawler. If you register the table in the glue catalog it can be read by Trino as well.

Can you share the errors you got when selecting?

Comment: Can you give an example on how can spark integrate with glue/ hive metastore so that Trino can automatically detect the table without me requiring to define the table. I am new to the ecosystem, so kindly pardon my innocence.

Answer (score 1):

Above is missing ARRAY keyword

```
create table trino.db_collection (
    col1 varchar,
    col2 varchar,
    col3 varchar
)with (
    external_location = 's3a://bucket/trino/db_collection/*',
    format = 'PARQUET',
    partitioned_by = ARRAY['col1','col2']
)
```

Comment: see this: https://trino.io/episodes/5.html